# ¿Cómo utilizar una variable de session en una función Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Quería utilizar una variable de sesión en una función javascript. ¿Cómo se combinan? La idea es que en una aplicación de pregunta y respuestas tipo test. Tengo la respuesta en la variable de sesión(php), y cuando el usuario pulse el botón, quiero que mediante una función javascript haga la comprobación.

Quería sabe cómo introducir dentro de una función, concretamente en un IF, poder comparar una VALUE con una variable de sesión.

Ejemplo (aproximado):

```
    <script language="javascript">
function comprobar(){
    var respuestaUsuario = document.getElementsById("boton").value;
    if(respuestaUsuario == $_SESSION['respuestaCorrecta']){
    alert("Respuesta Correcta")
    }
}
    </script>

    <button id=boton name=boton value="a" onclick="comprobar()">
```

¡Gracias!

Comment: Para estos casos yo uso una llamada ajax que devuelve el valor de la session o mejor el resultado de la evaluación en el lado del servidor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo abriendo y cerrando las llaves directamente en tu js, asi: (este editor de texto no permite la apertura de llaves de php):

```
if(respuestaUsuario == [abres_llaves_php] echo $_SESSION['respuestaCorrecta'] [cierras_llaves]){
```

o bien puedes utilizar un print_r, json_encode,... o lo que tu veas, lo que te sea más comodo o útil. Esto dependerá también de como sea tu variable (string, arrary, json,...).

No obstante, creo que es una mejor practica que hagas lo siguiente:

- Incluye tu variable en un input hidden:

  ```
   <input type="hidden" id="variable_sesion" value="[llaves_php] echo $_SESSION['respuestaCorrecta'] [cierra_llaves]">
  ```
- Y ahora recoge el valor en js:

  ```
  var valor_sesion = $('#valor_sesion').val();
  ```