# Mostrar el contador de un carrito en tiempo real (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

necesito mostrar el total de dinero que lleva un carrito de compras en tiempo real...
Actualmente lo hago de esta manera con php pero unicamente muestra el valor actualizado obviamente despues de actualizar la web

```
<a class="nav-link" id="flotante" href="carrito.php">Carrito1

        (<?php

          /*  $total = 0;
            if (isset($_SESSION['carrito'])) {
                $sesion = $_SESSION['carrito'];
                $arregloCarrito = $_SESSION['carrito'];
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($arregloCarrito); $i++) {


                    $sumar = $arregloCarrito[$i]['Precio'] * $arregloCarrito[$i]['Cantidad'];
                    $total = $total + $sumar;
                }
                echo '$ ' . $total;
            }*/
            ?>)</a>
```

y necesito mostrarlo en tiempo real... Creo deberia hacerlo en javascript pero no entiendo como leer esa variable de $_SESSION en javascript. Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Una idea es que podrías utilizar el localstorage https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage, cada vez que añades o eliminas algo al carrito, recuperar el valor de la propiedad del localstorage, sumas o restar el importe y muestras donde quieras.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar localStorage https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage para ir almacenando el valor del carrito, así tendrás siempre el valor del carrito actualizado y podrás recuperarlo donde quieras.

```js
function addcart(e){
  //Recuperar el valor actual del carrito
    let imp_cart = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    let imp = parseFloat(e.getAttribute("data-pvp"));
    imp_cart += imp;
  //Actualizas el valor del carrito con el nuevo importe
    localStorage.setItem('cart', imp);
}
```

```html
<a onclick = "addcart(this)" data-pvp='2.78'>2.78€</a>
```

Cada vez que haya una actualización del carrito, se ejecutará la función addcart, y posteriormente donde quieras mostrar el precio actualizado, bastará con recuperar la variable del localStorage.

```js
let imp_cart = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
```

En el caso de querer eliminar del carrito, la función sería análoga, pero recuperando el valor y restando al valor actual del carrito.

Comment: voy a ver como seria usando localstorage, el tema era que la mayoria del carrito ya trabaja con $_SESSION. De todas maneras fuera de localstorage no hay manera de hacerlo leyendo $_SESSION desde javascript?

Comment: Pégale un vistazo a https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/220502/c%C3%B3mo-utilizar-una-variable-de-session-en-una-funci%C3%B3n-javascript